# How to obtain data from multiple tables with same design in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database-design, multiple-tables

I am relatively new to SQL. I have tables `emp010115`, `emp020115`, `emp030115` .... upto `emp310115` for each date of January 2015 [name of the table denotes the date for which it belongs]. The design of all the tables are the same. Let the data in the first three table as below

`emp01012015`:

```
emp       tds       investmnt       tdate                 arrears
------------------------------------------------------------------  
 abc_______50_________15000_________2015-01-01 00:00:00_______325
 bca________0_________10000_________2015-01-01 00:00:00_______420
```

`emp02012015`:

```
emp       tds       investmnt       tdate                 arrears
------------------------------------------------------------------  
abc______520_________16000_________2015-01-02 00:00:00_______600
bca_______20_________14000_________2015-01-02 00:00:00_______740
```

`emp03012015`:

```
emp       tds       investmnt       tdate                 arrears
------------------------------------------------------------------  
abc______640_________11000_________2015-01-03 00:00:00_______850
bca______920_________13000_________2015-01-03 00:00:00_______650
```

I want the result of the query running on the table as below

```
emp          tds            tdate
-------------------------------------
abc____________50_________2015-01-01 00:00:00
abc___________520_________2015-01-02 00:00:00
abc___________640_________2015-01-03 00:00:00
bca_____________0_________2015-01-01 00:00:00
bca____________20_________2015-01-02 00:00:00
bca___________920_________2015-01-03 00:00:00
```

Can anyone please help me...

Comment: Just stop creating separate table for each day. Usually there is no reason to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't split tables like this but rather keep all data in the same table (unless there's a really good reason), but that said, what you can do is to use a `union all` query like this:

```
select emp, tds, tdate from emp01012015
union all
select emp, tds, tdate from emp02012015
union all 
select emp, tds, tdate from emp03012015
order by emp, tdate
```

This will create a single set of all the data which you then can do what you want with. The ordering won't be exactly as your example though.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68df6/1)